# What is the difference between atomic limit and hard core boson limit?

Tags: cold-atoms

In Bose-Hubbard model, we neglect the hopping term in atomic limit (U>>t) and the dominant interaction term result in a Mott Insulator phase. In hard core boson limit ($U \rightarrow \infty$), there is no double or higher occupancy are suppressed (n=0 or 1), so the interaction term in the Hamiltonian vanishes and the hopping term becomes dominant. Hard core boson limit and atomic limit are both in strongly interaction regime, but they seem have different results in Hamiltonian. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Atomic limit: $t\to 0$ with $U$ fixed. Hard-core limit: $t$ fixed and $U \to \infty$. In the latter case, the chemical potential is fixed to $U/2$ so that vacuum and the state with one boson is degenerate in energy.

Comment: Why is the chemical potential fixed to $U/2$ in hard core bosons?

Comment: In hard-core limit Hamiltonian, the interaction term can vanish, but one has to use the constraint n=0 or 1, and the Hilbert space will be truncated.